# Inner product between noisy and clean normal vectors

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, inner-products

Let $x \in \mathbb{R^n}$ so that $x \sim N(0, \Sigma)$, and let $y = x + e$ so that $e \sim N(0, \sigma^2 I)$.

That is, $y$ is $x$ + Gaussian noise.

Are there known results for $E[ \langle x, y \rangle]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $b_1, \dots, b_n\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be the basis in which the symmetric matrix $\Sigma$ is diagonal $\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n)$. Let $x_k$, $y_k$ and $e_k$ be the coefficients of $x$, $y$ and $e$ respectively in the basis $b_1, \dots, b_n$

$$
x = x_1b_1 + \dots + x_nb_n\\
y = y_1b_1 + \dots + y_nb_n\\
e = e_1b_1 + \dots + e_nb_n.
$$

We have

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\langle x, y\rangle] &= \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{k=1}^nx_ky_k\right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{k=1}^nx_k^2 + \sum_{k=1}^nx_ke_k\right] \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n\mathbb{E}[x_k^2] + \sum_{k=1}^n\mathbb{E}[x_ke_k] \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_k + 0 \\
&= \mathrm{tr}\,\Sigma
\end{align}
$$

where we assume the noise $e$ is independent of $x$.

Comment: Thanks, In fact, you don't use their distribution, right?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't use the fact that the r.v.s are Gaussian, but I used the fact that the mean of $x$ is zero and that its covariance matrix $\Sigma$ exists. I also assumed that $e$ is independent of $x$.